# Separating each 3 integer with dots or commas

Tags: c#

Lets say i have an integer 200000 parsed from string.I want to make the printed result separated each 3 character counted from back

e.x. : 200000 => 200.000 or 20000 => 20.000

so how i could do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please do at least a basic search here before posting. That would include looking through the suggested questions you see before posting your answer. I found the solution to your question in the related list to the right of your question, in the third item down from the top, which pretty clearly shows you didn't put any effort into finding one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string formatting pattern:

```
int number = 200000;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("###,###"));
```

Comment: How if the number is already string ?